# Does JavaFX work in 32-bit Windows? (or with a 32-bit JVM)?

Tags: java, macos, 64-bit, javafx, 32-bit

Since JavaFX only works for 64-bit Linux and 64-bit OS X as far as I know (because the newer verison of Java hasn't been released in 32-bit), I'm curious if JavaFX is able to work on 32-bit Windows.  Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Eh?  Where did you get this from?  JavaFX works on *any* JVM.

Comment: Funny, usually the question is phrased the other way around. (Does it work on *64-bit* Windows?) Why would it not support a 32-bit JVM? :)

Comment: JavaFX works on any newer JVM.  I noticed after googling that JavaFX doesn't appear to be supported on 32-bit OS X or 32-bit Linux.  Sun/Oracle released the JavaFX-capable 64-bit JVM but not 32-bit one yet.

Comment: For anyone looking for JavaFX 12.0.0 that is built for Windows 32-bit, you can find it here: https://www.mediafire.com/file/2jfij4tj83702md/javafx-sdk-12-32bit.zip/file .. I built it using these instructions: https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/Building+OpenJFX

Comment: @Eng.Fouad, I have heard that there is a problem with webkit for javaFx 32 bit, is it true ? or is it solved in your zip ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does. I'm doing it right now ;)

Answer (score 0):

Solution I've found on this using the Eclipse Photon 32 bit, it was to add a User Library which contains the jfxrt.jar file from the jre corresponding version of the java sdk. In this way you avoid trying to rebuild the java fx packages for each class builder version or os version.